# Video card for my motherboard

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, compatibility

My motherboard is [Biostar G41D3C](http://www.biostar.com.tw/app/en/mb/introduction.php?S_ID=518#specification). My CPU is Intel Core 2 Quad and I have 4 GB RAM.

Will GTX 1050 Ti work on my PC?

How can I know if a video card will work on my PC?

Update:

the interface of gtx 1050 ti is `PCI Express 3.0 x16` and mine is `1 x PCI-E x16 Slot` so it won't work?

is that the way to check if a motherboard and video card are compatible?

My PSU is truerated 580w

Comment: We need to know your power supply too.

Comment: It will work, but it probably won't work well, and when playing games the bottleneck will most likely be your CPU. That's a VERY old computer to be putting a VERY new GPU into.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf my psu is a 580w.

Comment: @music2myear i am planning to buy a new motherboard and a new processor but i don't have a budget for now. So im going to buy a video card for now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your motherboard uses PCIe v1.0a, and the GTX 1050 Ti uses the PCIe v3.0. While v3.0 is backwards compatible, it's possible to use GTX 1050 Ti on your system, but you may notice some performance loss OR might run just fine.

Also, I'm not sure which power supply are you using, but make sure you have a sufficient power supply for your system before any upgrade to avoid any power issues.

Comment: i am using 580w. will it be alright?

Comment: @audreyruaburo, that can only be answered by looking at ALL of your components and adding up their peak power drawn, and making sure that is less than your PSUs maximum output.

Comment: As @audreyruaburo said, and also, you need to know what the actual number of watts (Continuous Wattage) that your psu can deliver. You will know that from the psu label or on its website (from manufacture's website).